# Bootstrap: how to position an element horizontally anywhere in a grid design?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am learning Bootstrap. I am using Bootstrap for a design with fixed width. From the online documentation, I know it is easy to position elements starting from a column. For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bootstrap version</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            padding-top: 60px;
            padding-bottom: 40px;
        }
    </style>
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="learn.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="span3" style="background-color:grey">span3</div>
    <div class="span5" style="background-color:pink"><div id="text">span5 text</div></div>
    <div class="span4" style="background-color:navy">span4</div>
    </div>
</div> 


    <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>    
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

In the above,

```
<div id="text">span5 text</div>
```

horizontally starts exactly where the fourth column starts. I would like to know how Bootstrap expert users use CSS to position

```
<div id="text">span5 text</div>
```

to make it start between the third and fourth columns or ends between the eighth and ninth columns.

I am thinking about using either:

```
<style>
#text {
margin-left:-10px;
}
</style>
```

or

```
<style>
#text {
    position:relative;
    left:-10px;
}
</style>
```

to position the div, but not sure whether which is preferred and would like to know what experts do and some other ways.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean from the middle of the "margin" between columns?

Comment: Yes. I would like to position that div to anywhere horizontally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, there is always a margin-left (or gutter) between the Bootstrap spans (see here: http://bootply.com/64463). If you want to override this, it is possible with CSS, but then you'll lose the responsive benefits of Bootstrap, because the element will be removed from the normal page flow.

A better option may be a custom Bootstrap build with no gutter: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html#variables

Or, you can create a custom CSS class that you apply to rows as needed like this Gutter-less example: http://bootply.com/61712

Comment: Thanks a million for your input!

Comment: Skelly, should I use the css in the post just for one or two cases (not the site-wide need)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I use this solution, that working for me:

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="height:100%;">
  <div>
    <table style="height:100%;width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            head 1
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            head 2
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            body 1
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            body 2
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            foot 1
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            foot 2
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

[image]